# Can I edit MS SQL stored procedures in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea

I googled a bit but didn't find an answer.

Is there a way to edit (or at least view) MS SQL stored procedures in IntelliJ IDEA ? I know I can directly fetch them from system tables but perhaps there is a plugin I don't know ?

I use IDEA 11.

Comment: According to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84426 it will be supported in IDEA 12. Next EAP build to be published at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP will have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @CrazyCoder advice I just downloaded EAP build .29 and the feature works there!