# how can I edit MS SQL Server stored procedure from IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for development. I connect to MSSQL Server successfully, and all my tables, etc load up. 
I can see all the tables. 
I can see the name and inputs of stored procedures.

However, when I attempt to edit the stored procedure by double-clicking, I get the following message:

```
-- Definition loading failed:
-- java.sql.SQLException: The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
--  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
--  in RemoteStatementImpl.executeQuery(RemoteStatementImpl.java:141)
--  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
--  in DbImplUtil.concatStringResults(DbImplUtil.java:428)
```

I read on a few blogs that there's no native support, has anyone found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to edit stored procedures in Intellij IDEA 12 and above : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84426.

This is relevant: [Can I edit MS SQL stored procedures in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962118/can-i-edit-ms-sql-stored-procedures-in-intellij-idea)

That being the case, perhaps this is a bug that you've encountered and it's worth raising it on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ ?

#### Update

I just created a simple Stored Procedure in Oracle 11.2.x and edited it in Intellij IDEA 13 without any issues.

Try creating and editing the same in MSSQL Server ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procPrintHelloWorld
IS
BEGIN     
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
  PRINT N'Hello World!';     
END;
/
```